# Download and play partial audio files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, gstreamer, audio-streaming

I have an audio streaming application that uses requests to download the audio file and then played using Gstreamer.

I want to trim the first few seconds of all the audio files that i have. I could use ffmpeg to trim but that would waste cpu resources on my embedded platform and also waste network bandwidth

(The number of songs are around 1000, and they get downloaded continously, so it does make a difference)

I have tried downloading partial file using the range header in requests but that doesn't work. I can't play the file.

Can someone please tell me how i can make this work?

The audio files are generally .m4a / .webm but they are extracted from youtube so can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an uneasy task.. there is no clean way how to do it..

you can probably use the [valve](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-valve.html) element set it to drop by default.. 
and then put some timer which sets the drop to false..

not sure how this will work, you need to try.

[Here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/How-to-drop-first-X-frames-or-first-X-seconds-of-video-td4660321.html) are some hints:

Comment: I've already implemented a seek using gstreamer but i would prefer if there was a way to partially download the file  in first place..

(To be clear, i don't stream using gstreamer. I have a custom caching mechanism. Gstreamer plays the cached audio file)